# Boxes not resizing to page

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS & have been creating a website. My 2 main boxes aren't resizing with the page, while everything else is. There are 2 other boxes that do resize, the navbar and footer, but the center "workspace" box doesn't. (the boxes that aren't resizing are divs with classes "workspace" & "workspaceMain"). I've tried using different positions & margin tricks, and I've been looking around online to try and find something to fix the issue but I haven't found any working fixes yet.

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
body {
    background-color:rgb(250, 235, 215);
}

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.workspace {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color:#ddd;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 750px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.workspace button {
    margin-top: 500;
    margin-left: 375px;
    background-color:darkgrey;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    border-color:black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 100px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
}
.workspace button:hover, .workspace button:focus  {
    border-color:white;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.workspaceMain {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -400px;
    margin-left: 175px;
    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
    width: 1125px;
    height: 562.5px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 7.5px;
}
#projectName {
    font-size: 17.5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: black;
}
.botInfo {
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 92%;
}
.botInfo input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 30px;
}
#workInfo {
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.actions {
    margin-top: 350px;
}
.actions select {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.actions:hover, .actions:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.footer {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 2000;
    padding: 10px;
}
.footer p {
    font-size: 15px;
    color:aliceblue;
    text-align: left;
}
.footer button {
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.footer button:focus {
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.darkMode {
    background-color: rgb(77, 76, 75);
}
```

```html
<body onload="pageLoad()" id="mainBody">
    <h1>Workspace</h1>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="../landing/index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="workspace.html">Workspace</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="workspace">
        <div id="workInfo">
            <input placeholder="Project Name" id="projectName" spellcheck="true"></input>
            <div class="botInfo">
                Prefix: <input placeholder="Prefix" id="prefix" spellcheck="true"></input>
                Status: <input placeholder="Status" id="status" spellcheck="true"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="actions" id="actions">
                <select>
                    <option value="">Commands</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="projectCreate" onclick="projectCreate()">Create a project</button>
        <div id="workspaceMain" class="workspaceMain">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Production: (不滅)Shinigami</p>
        <button onclick="colorMode()" id="colorMode">Light Mode</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workspace and workspace-main element have absolute values for width and height (pixels). So they won't resize. There are two ways I can recommend. You can use media queries at some breakpoints or you can use relative values like percentage.